# How to access field from strict serde_json deserialization with tags

Tags: rust

I get `Some(Address{...})` in the Address field of `data` which is expected. I can see it from the debug printout.

But `&data.Address = &data.Address.unwrap();`

gives me static error saying: **"no field `Address` on type Profile"**.

```
let mut data:Profile = serde_json::from_str(json_string).unwrap();
&data.Address = &data.Address.unwrap();

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug, Serialize)]
#[serde(tag = "m_tag")]
pub enum Profile {
   Data{
    #[serde(rename="FirstName")] // to comply with Rust coding standards
    first_name:String,
    LastName: String,
    Age: u32,
    Address:  Option<Address>,
    PhoneNumbers: Vec<String>
   },
   Data2{
    #[serde(rename="FirstName")] // to comply with Rust coding standards
    first_name:String,
    LastName: String,
    Age: u32,
   },

}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Address {
    Street: String,
    City: String,
    Country: String
}
```

UPDATED:
Q1) I can unwrap the value BUt I would like to update the &data.Address to it.
But i'm back to original problem where &data is a `Profile` type and doesn't have the `Address` field.

```
 match &data {
        Profile::Data {
            first_name,
            LastName,
            Age,
            Address,
            PhoneNumbers,
        } => data.Address =  &Address.as_ref().unwrap(),
        Profile::Data2 {
           first_name,
           LastName,
           Age,
        } => println!("ok"),
    }
```

Comment: You need to match on `Profile::Data` or `Profile::Data2` to access the data inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

There's no need to create an Enum if the fields overlap. It's better to declare the fields that are not guaranteed to be there as optional:

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug, Serialize)]
struct Profile {
  #[serde(rename="FirstName")]
  first_name:String,
  LastName: String,
  Age: u32,
  Address:  Option<Address>,
  PhoneNumbers: Option<Vec<String>>
};
```

So that now it's guaranteed that the type `Profile` has an `Address` field:

```
let data:Profile = serde_json::from_str(json_string).unwrap();

println!("{:?}", data.Address);
```

Here's a code example working in the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dd4972eddb2b87cfcb46f348aa80edcd).

Comment: Ty, but in the first part of your answer: "serde_json::from_str"  I get an error "type annotations needed

cannot infer type for type parameter `T` declared on the function `from_str`
"

Comment: You can type the generic function like this:

`serde_json::from_str<Profile>(json_string).unwrap()`

Comment: Ah yes, ``` serde_json::from_str::<Profile>(json_string).unwrap()``` worked . But then I got another error at the colon " data1: Profile...". Error : "expected one of `=>`, `@`, `if`, or `|`, found `:`
"

Comment: Sorry, that's apparently invalid syntax when pattern matching in Rust. I have updated my answer with an example running in the Rust Playground.

Comment: Ty, What I wanted to do from the beginning is to set a value. But getting an error after the set. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e9b2ae94749bc672ee4c5e87827c0731

Comment: I'm coming from a python background. And what I want to do is load a json from a url, modify the sub documents and save the json. It is a common task... I can't seem to find any tutorials on it.

Comment: I see. Mutability in Rust is different to pretty much any other programming language. Here's an updated Rust Playground example based on your last message: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1cc119dbfc2ef25cc2f8b55c378197f3